# How to show a label and text box in a same row using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Name&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" class="span3">
    </div>
```

this is not working for me, I dont wanna use 'form-horizontal' class or a table for this. I have tried with row and row-fluid class but its not working.

Comment: Which class you are using for this??

Comment: i have tried using row, row fluid etc, but cant get it in a same row

Comment: I can do it by using 'form-horizontal' but i dont want my elements inside a form

Comment: You can wrap your code with `<div class="form-horizontal">`. You don't need to have a `form` to use `form-horizontal`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wrap your code with `<div class="form-horizontal">`. You don't need to have a `form` to use `form-horizontal`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xYyqz/):

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group row-fluid form-inline">
        <label for="name" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Name&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" class="span3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want horizontal form layout. This can be achieved by wrappping your code between a div having class as form-horizontal.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="control-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Name&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" class="span3">
    </div>
</div>
```

To learn more click [here](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/forms-tutorial.php)